# How to read json file into java with simple JSON library

Tags: java, json, parsing, json-simple

I want to read this `JSON` file with java using json simple library.

My `JSON` file looks like this:

```
[  
    {  
        "name":"John",
        "city":"Berlin",
        "cars":[  
            "audi",
            "bmw"
        ],
        "job":"Teacher"
    },
    {  
        "name":"Mark",
        "city":"Oslo",
        "cars":[  
            "VW",
            "Toyata"
        ],
        "job":"Doctor"
    }
]
```

This is the java code I wrote to read this file:

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {     
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\file.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) obj;

            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
            System.out.println(name);

            String city = (String) jsonObject.get("city");
            System.out.println(city);

            String job = (String) jsonObject.get("job");
            System.out.println(job);

            // loop array
            JSONArray cars = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cars");
            Iterator<String> iterator = cars.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
             System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
>     at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:24)

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? The whole file is a array and there are objects and another array (cars) in the whole array of the file. But i dont know how I can parse the whole array into a java array. I hope somebody can help me with a code line which I am missing in my code.

Thanks

Comment: Please refer the below answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463414/what-s-the-best-way-to-load-a-jsonobject-from-a-json-text-file

Comment: don't want to use data model? it's as easy as a pie, if you use gson you can simply parse it by s.th like this: `List<YOUR_USER_MODEL> info = new Gson().fromJson(YOUR_JSON_STRING, new TypeToken<List<YOUR_USER_MODEL>>() {}.getType())`

Answer (score 110):

> ***The whole file is an array and there are objects and other arrays (e.g. cars) in the whole array of the file.***

As you say, the outermost layer of your JSON blob is an array.  Therefore, your parser will return a `JSONArray`.  You can then get `JSONObject`s from the array ...

```
  JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\exer4-courses.json"));

  for (Object o : a)
  {
    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

    String name = (String) person.get("name");
    System.out.println(name);

    String city = (String) person.get("city");
    System.out.println(city);

    String job = (String) person.get("job");
    System.out.println(job);

    JSONArray cars = (JSONArray) person.get("cars");

    for (Object c : cars)
    {
      System.out.println(c+"");
    }
  }
```

For reference, see "Example 1" on the [json-simple decoding example](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) page.

Comment: Thanks. It reads the first object course, instructor, students array and title object. How can I read the next ones too?

Comment: Well, you want to process all of the items in the array in a loop.  My code just gets you the first item (`a.get(0)`) because that was the closest match to your original code.  The json-simple documentation says a `JSONArray` is `java.util.List`, so you can iterate over the elements just like you would a normal list.  Is that enough to go on?

Comment: I have tried that but it did not work. Can you give me a code example

Comment: @billz: I don't have the library to be able to execute and test this -- but I've edited the answer with my guess.

Comment: This works great ! 
Please note: use the import as is in this example (i.e. with 'simple'), otherwise it will not allow 'for each'.
Wrong:
     import org.json.JSONArray;
     import org.json.JSONObject;
Correct: 
      import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
      import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

Comment: Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 156.

Comment: It's giving me error as :- Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable on line    for (Object o : a)

Comment: @ShubhamJain: which JSON library are you using? The one in the answer is one where a `JSONArray` is an `Iterable` - looks like yours does not. Here's the source of the [class in this answer](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONArray.java).

Comment: very creative variable names

Comment: how to give the FileReader a relative path, may be from /resources folder

Comment: `parser` from which library (import) is it?

Comment: ` JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();`

Answer (score 83):

You can use jackson library and simply use these 3 lines to convert your json file to Java Object.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.json");
testObj = mapper.readValue(is, Test.class);
```

Comment: May i know the ObjectMapper jar links to download.

Comment: @RenceAbishek you import it with `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;`

Answer (score 24):

Add Jackson databind:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0.pr2</version>
</dependency>
```

Create DTO class with related fields and read JSON file:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ExampleClass example = objectMapper.readValue(new File("example.json"), ExampleClass.class);
```

Answer (score 15):

Reading from JsonFile

```
public static ArrayList<Employee> readFromJsonFile(String fileName){
        ArrayList<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        try{
            String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(text);
            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("employees");

            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
                String name = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                short salary = Short.parseShort(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("salary"));
                String position = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("position");
                byte years_in_company = Byte.parseByte(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("years_in_company")); 
                if (position.compareToIgnoreCase("manager") == 0){
                    result.add(new Manager(name, salary, position, years_in_company));
                }
                else{
                    result.add(new OrdinaryEmployee(name, salary, position, years_in_company));
                }
            }           
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Use google-simple library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Please find the sample code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        //Use JSONObject for simple JSON and JSONArray for array of JSON.
        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(
              new FileReader("/resources/config.json"));//path to the JSON file.

        String json = data.toJSONString();
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Use JSONObject for simple JSON like `{"id":"1","name":"ankur"}` and JSONArray for array of JSON like `[{"id":"1","name":"ankur"},{"id":"2","name":"mahajan"}]`.

Answer (score 7):

Might be of help for someone else facing the same issue.You can load the file as string and then can convert the string to jsonobject to access the values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.JSONObject;
String myJson = new Scanner(new File(filename)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
JSONObject myJsonobject = new JSONObject(myJson);
```

Answer (score 5):

[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) can be used here:

```
public Object getObjectFromJsonFile(String jsonData, Class classObject) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject object = (JsonObject) parser.parse(jsonData);
    return gson.fromJson(object, classObject);
}
```

Comment: `JsonParser()` is deprecated.  Used `gson.fromJson()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Delete_01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
            IOException, ParseException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(
                "delete_01.json"));

        for (Object o : jsonArray) {
            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

            String strName = (String) person.get("name");
            System.out.println("Name::::" + strName);

            String strCity = (String) person.get("city");
            System.out.println("City::::" + strCity);

            JSONArray arrays = (JSONArray) person.get("cars");
            for (Object object : arrays) {
                System.out.println("cars::::" + object);
            }
            String strJob = (String) person.get("job");
            System.out.println("Job::::" + strJob);
            System.out.println();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is the working solution to your problem statement as,

```
File file = new File("json-file.json");
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(obj.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      System.out.println(jsonObject.get("name"));
      System.out.println(jsonObject.get("city"));
      System.out.println(jsonObject.get("job"));
      jsonObject.getJSONArray("cars").forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this example helps too

I have done java coding in a similar way for the below json array example as follows :

following is the json data format : stored as "EMPJSONDATA.json"

[{"EMPNO":275172,"EMP_NAME":"Rehan","DOB":"29-02-1992","DOJ":"10-06-2013","ROLE":"JAVA DEVELOPER"},

{"EMPNO":275173,"EMP_NAME":"G.K","DOB":"10-02-1992","DOJ":"11-07-2013","ROLE":"WINDOWS ADMINISTRATOR"},

{"EMPNO":275174,"EMP_NAME":"Abiram","DOB":"10-04-1992","DOJ":"12-08-2013","ROLE":"PROJECT ANALYST"}

{"EMPNO":275174,"EMP_NAME":"Mohamed Mushi","DOB":"10-04-1992","DOJ":"12-08-2013","ROLE":"PROJECT ANALYST"}]

```
public class Jsonminiproject {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("F:/JSON DATA/EMPJSONDATA.json"));
        for (Object o : a)
        {
            JSONObject employee = (JSONObject) o;

            Long no = (Long) employee.get("EMPNO");
            System.out.println("Employee Number : " + no);

            String st = (String) employee.get("EMP_NAME");
            System.out.println("Employee Name : " + st);

            String dob = (String) employee.get("DOB");
            System.out.println("Employee DOB : " + dob);

            String doj = (String) employee.get("DOJ");
            System.out.println("Employee DOJ : " + doj);

            String role = (String) employee.get("ROLE");
            System.out.println("Employee Role : " + role);

            System.out.println("\n");

        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}

}
```

Comment: Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 156.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.json;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class ReadJSONFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/My Workspace/JSON Test/file.json"));

            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) array.get(0);

            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
            System.out.println(name);

            String city = (String) jsonObject.get("city");
            System.out.println(city);

            String job = (String) jsonObject.get("job");
            System.out.println(job);

            // loop array
            JSONArray cars = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cars");
            Iterator<String> iterator = cars.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You JSON file has a array of object so travers through the array

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when you are importing the org. json library for JSONObject class. Instead you need to import org.json.simple library.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final JsonParser JSON_PARSER = new JsonParser();    
private static final String FILE_PATH = "configuration/data.json";

private JsonObject readJsonDataFromFile() {
    try {
        File indexFile = new File(FILE_PATH);
        String fileData = Files.toString(indexFile, Charsets.UTF_8);
        return (JsonObject) JSON_PARSER.parse(fileData);
    } catch (IOException | JsonParseException e) {
        String error = String.format("Error while reading file %s", FILE_PATH);
        log.error(error);
        throw new RuntimeException(error, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class JsonParser {

    public static JSONObject parse(String file) {
        InputStream is = JsonParser.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
        assert is != null;
        return new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(is));
    }
}
// Read Json 
    JSONObject deviceObj = new JSONObject(JsonParser.parse("Your Json filename").getJSONObject(deviceID).toString());
```

Perform logic to iterate

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
public class JsonParserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/json.txt"))); 
        JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(data);
        JsonObject json = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(json.get("userId"));
        System.out.println(json.get("id"));
        System.out.println(json.get("title"));
        System.out.println(json.get("completed"));
    }
}

Use the below repositay from GSON.
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: bravo! `gson` is good choice, but, add sample of `JsonArray` as this question requested. in your code you can add `System.out.println(StreamSupport.stream(json.getAsJsonArray("cars").spliterator(), false).map(i -> i.getAsString()).collect(Collectors.toList());` or any equivalent phrase

Comment: and also, pay attention to the json, the root is an array of objects. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Sample Json

```
{
    "per_page": 3,
    "total": 12,
    "data": [{
            "last_name": "Bluth",
            "id": 1,
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg",
            "first_name": "George"
        },
        {
            "last_name": "Weaver",
            "id": 2,
            //"avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg",
            "first_name": "Janet"
        },
        {
            "last_name": "Wong",
            "id": 3,
            //"avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg",
            "first_name": "Emma"
        }
    ],
    "page": 1,
    "total_pages": 4
}
```

---

First If statement will convert the single data from the body
Second if statement will differentiate the JsonArray object

```
public static String getvalueJpath(JSONObject responseJson, String Jpath ) {
        Object obj = responseJson;
        for(String s : Jpath.split("/"))
            if (s.isEmpty())
                if(!(s.contains("[") || s.contains("]")))
                    obj = ((JSONObject) obj).get(s);
                else
                    if(s.contains("[") || s.contains("]"))
                        obj = ((JSONArray)((JSONObject)obj).get(s.split("\\[")[0])).get(Integer.parseInt(s.split("//[")[1].replaceAll("]", "")));

        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Jackson library. Sorted this problem by verifying the json on JSONLint.com and then using Jackson. Below is the code for the same.

```
 Main Class:-

String jsonStr = "[{\r\n" + "       \"name\": \"John\",\r\n" + "        \"city\": \"Berlin\",\r\n"
                + "         \"cars\": [\r\n" + "            \"FIAT\",\r\n" + "          \"Toyata\"\r\n"
                + "     ],\r\n" + "     \"job\": \"Teacher\"\r\n" + "   },\r\n" + " {\r\n"
                + "     \"name\": \"Mark\",\r\n" + "        \"city\": \"Oslo\",\r\n" + "        \"cars\": [\r\n"
                + "         \"VW\",\r\n" + "            \"Toyata\"\r\n" + "     ],\r\n"
                + "     \"job\": \"Doctor\"\r\n" + "    }\r\n" + "]";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        MyPojo jsonObj[] = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, MyPojo[].class);

        for (MyPojo itr : jsonObj) {

            System.out.println("Val of getName is: " + itr.getName());
            System.out.println("Val of getCity is: " + itr.getCity());
            System.out.println("Val of getJob is: " + itr.getJob());
            System.out.println("Val of getCars is: " + itr.getCars() + "\n");

        }

POJO:

public class MyPojo {

private List<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();

private String name;

private String job;

private String city;

public List<String> getCars() {
    return cars;
}

public void setCars(List<String> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getJob() {
    return job;
}

public void setJob(String job) {
    this.job = job;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
} }

  RESULT:-
         Val of getName is: John
         Val of getCity is: Berlin
         Val of getJob is: Teacher
         Val of getCars is: [FIAT, Toyata]

          Val of getName is: Mark
          Val of getCity is: Oslo
          Val of getJob is: Doctor
          Val of getCars is: [VW, Toyata]
```

Answer (score 0):

**your json file look like this**

[image]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
public class JSONReadFromTheFileTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
      try {
         Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/Users/User/Desktop/course.json"));
         JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
         String name = (String)jsonObject.get("Name");
         String course = (String)jsonObject.get("Course");
         JSONArray subjects = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("Subjects");
         System.out.println("Name: " + name);
         System.out.println("Course: " + course);
         System.out.println("Subjects:");
         Iterator iterator = subjects.iterator();
         while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
         }
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

the output is

```
Name: Raja
Course: MCA
Subjects:
subject1: MIS
subject2: DBMS
subject3: UML
```

[took it from here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-we-read-a-json-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
      Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Local Disk/file.json"));

     // JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
      JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
      
      JSONObject orchestration = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("orchestration");
     

      JSONObject trigger = (JSONObject) orchestration.get("trigger-definition");
     

      JSONObject schedule = (JSONObject) trigger.get("schedule");
    
       JSONObject trade = (JSONObject) schedule.get("trade-query");
    
     // loop array
      JSONArray filter = (JSONArray) trade.get("filter");
   
  
      for (Object o : filter) {
          JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

          String strName = (String) person.get("name");
          System.out.println("Name::::" + strName);

          String operand = (String) person.get("operand");
          System.out.println("City::::" + operand);

          String value = (String) person.get("value");
          System.out.println("value::::" + value);
      }
     
      JSONArray parameter = (JSONArray) trade.get("parameter");
      for (Object o : parameter) {
          JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

          String strName = (String) person.get("name");
          System.out.println("Name::::" + strName);

          String value = (String) person.get("value");
          System.out.println("value::::" + value);
      }


  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
      //Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Local Disk/file.json"));
      
       // create object mapper instance
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // convert JSON string to Book object
        Object obj = mapper.readValue(Paths.get("C:/Local Disk/file.json").toFile(), Object.class);

        // print book
        System.out.println(obj);

        String jsonInString = new Gson().toJson(obj);
        JSONObject mJSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonInString);
        
        System.out.println("value::::" + mJSONObject);  
      
      JSONObject orchestration = (JSONObject) mJSONObject.get("orchestration");
     

      JSONObject trigger = (JSONObject) orchestration.get("trigger-definition");
     

      JSONObject schedule = (JSONObject) trigger.get("schedule");
    
       JSONObject trade = (JSONObject) schedule.get("trade-query");
    
     // loop array
      JSONArray filter = (JSONArray) trade.get("filter");
   
  
      for (Object o : filter) {
          JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

          String strName = (String) person.get("name");
          System.out.println("Name::::" + strName);

          String operand = (String) person.get("operand");
          System.out.println("City::::" + operand);

          String value = (String) person.get("value");
          System.out.println("value::::" + value);
      }
     
      JSONArray parameter = (JSONArray) trade.get("parameter");
      for (Object o : parameter) {
          JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

          String strName = (String) person.get("name");
          System.out.println("Name::::" + strName);

          String value = (String) person.get("value");
          System.out.println("value::::" + value);
      }


  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add Jackson dependency to use ObjectMapper in your `pom.xml` file.

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.12.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

In your main class `App.java`, use the mapper to convert your JSON file to JsonNode

```
public static void main(Strings[] args) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode json = mapper.readValue(new File("/path/to/file"), JsonNode.class);
    json.fields()
            .forEachRemaining((field) -> {
                String key = field.getKey();
                JsonNode value = field.getValue(); // value can be yet another JSON
               // Do your stuff with the keys and values here.
            });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class,name = "Dog"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Bagamol.class,name="Bagamol")
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use readAllBytes.

`return String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: The Original question asks about reading into an JSON Object not a string.