# How to convert a records of a json file into a List in scala

Tags: scala

I am doing some handson on Scala

I have a json file named simple.json

```
"employees":[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

I want  read this json file from and keep the values of this values in a scala List

Expected output :

```
  List("John|Doe", "Anna|Smith", "Peter|Jones")
```

I am not able to proceed with the scala file

```
package pack1
import scala.io.Source
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
   object ss {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {       
    val mySource=Source.fromFile("C:\\inputfiles\\simple.json").getLines().mkString
    println(mySource)
    val parser = new JSONParser();
    val jArray = parser.parse(mySource);


 }

 }
```

How do I proceed with the code to get the expected output

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36290229/5344058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `play-json`

if you are using sbt project. Add following line to dependencies in your project.

*build.sbt*

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.5.4")
```

*Source code*

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("<file-path>").getLines.mkString
val json = Json.parse("{" + lines.replaceAll("""\n""", "").trim + "}")
val list = (json \ "employees").as[List[JsValue]]
           .map(name => s"""${(name \ "firstName").as[String]}|${(name \ "lastName").as[String]}""")
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala>  import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val str = """ {"employees" : [ {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"} ] }""".trim
str: String = {"employees" : [ {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"} ] }

scala> val json = Json.parse(str)
json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"employees":[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}]}

scala> val list = (json \ "employees").as[List[JsValue]].map(name => s"""${(name \ "firstName").as[String]}|${(name \ "lastName").as[String]}""")
list: List[String] = List(John|Doe)
```

Note that below string is not a valid json

```
val str = """
"employees":[
              {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
              {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
              {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
            ] """.stripMargin
```

This has to be  wrapped inside a `{ }` for `Json.parse` to parse properly.

```
val validJsonStr = "{" + str + "}"
```