# Taking user input retrieving details from json file and print it in java

Tags: java, json

Data.json:

```
{"UniversalWord": {"UniversalWord": [
   {
      "uw_id": 1,
      "HeadWord": {"word": "aare"},
      "Restriction": {"SemanticRelations": {"feat": [
         {
            "att": "restriction_type",
            "value": "iof"
         },
         {
            "att": "target",
            "val": " "
         }
      ]}},
      "NLDescription": {
         "Gloss": {"feat": {
            "att": "Description",
            "val": "\"A RIVER IN NORTH CENTRAL SWITZERLAND THAT RUNS NORTHEAST INTO THE RHINE\""
         }},
         "Lemma": {"feat": {
            "att": "word",
            "val": "aare"
         }},
         "Example": {"feat": {
            "att": "description",
            "val": "\"\""
         }}
      },
      "MetaInfo": {
         "Frequency": {"freq": ""},
         "UWSource": {"Source_id": "WORDNET"}
      }
   },
   {
      "uw_id": 2,
      "HeadWord": {"word": "aarhus"},
      "Restriction": {"SemanticRelations": {"feat": [
         {
            "att": "restriction_type",
            "value": "iof"
         },
         {
            "att": "target",
            "val": " "
         },
         {
            "att": "restriction_type",
            "value": "equ"
         },
         {
            "att": "target",
            "val": " "
         }
      ]}},
      "NLDescription": {
         "Gloss": {"feat": {
            "att": "Description",
            "val": "\"PORT CITY OF DENMARK IN EASTERN JUTLAND\""
         }},
         "Lemma": {"feat": {
            "att": "word",
            "val": "aarhus"
         }},
         "Example": {"feat": {
            "att": "description",
            "val": "\"\""
         }}
      },
      "MetaInfo": {
         "Frequency": {"freq": ""},
         "UWSource": {"Source_id": "WORDNET"}
      }
   }
]}}
```

Required output:

```
Word Searched: aare
uwid = 1
headword = aare
semantic relation value = iof
target = ""
gloss = A RIVER IN NORTH CENTRAL SWITZERLAND THAT RUNS NORTHEAST INTO THE RHINE
lemma = aare
example = ""
frequency = ""
Source_ID = wordnet
```

code.java

```
public class SearchJson 
{
    public void SearchValueInJson(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        try
        {
            String jsonData = sb.toString();
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            iterateJson(jobj,map);
            System.out.println(map.toString());


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
     public void iterateJson(JSONObject jobj,Map map)
        {
             for(Object o : jobj.keySet())
             {
                 if(jobj.get(o.toString())instanceof JSONObject)
                     iterateJson(jobj.getJSONObject(o.toString()),map);
                 else
                     map.put(o.toString(), jobj.get(o.toString()));
             }
        }
}
```

this code i tried but it is not giving me expected output.

How to retrieve this information from the json file? I'm not getting the proper solution for it. Please give code for this. And assume that you don't know key values of data on that basis have to retrieve.

Comment: Have tried something? if yes, show us the code. If not try out something first.

Comment: Use one of the many json parses that are available

Comment: @MadProgrammer JSON parsing seems a little overkill if OP simply wants to print a file.

Comment: @shmosel *"retrieving details **from** json file and print it in java"* - To me, that means parsing to find what they are looking for and print the results - but what do I know :P

Comment: No  OP whats to traverse through data and print few attributes only.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926353/how-to-read-json-file-into-java-with-simple-json-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: no i tried according to above link also but i m not able to get that how to do

Comment: @MadProgrammer it will be more convinient for me if u provide a code that parses the file and give expected output. As i m new to json parsing it results in many issues so.

Comment: @Smit The above code i have tried bt not getting expected output.

Comment: @Suchitkumar no it is not duplicate one of that . you can have look to json file its different it contains nested JSONArrays and JSONObjects. Help me out for its solution

Comment: I'm not saying that it is duplicate .i just saying have a look at that answer and try.

Comment: @Suchitkumar i had a look to it and tried it also bt not giving me proper output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code snippet, this may solve your problem.

JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);

```
        JSONArray arr = jobj.getJSONObject("UniversalWord").getJSONArray("UniversalWord");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
        {
            String uw_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("uw_id");
            System.out.println(uw_id);
            String headWord = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("HeadWord").getString("word");
            System.out.println(headWord);
            String nLDescription = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("NLDescription").getJSONObject("Gloss").getJSONObject("feat").getString("val");
            System.out.println(nLDescription);
        }
```