# Java 8 JSON-simple - How can i read a subitem?

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I have a Problem in Java, specially in work with the JSON-simple Library. I have found here a code, they does work in the level of a parent node from a json-file but at my case, i read a json-file with childs under the parents.

Link to the code: [How to read json file into java with simple JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926353/how-to-read-json-file-into-java-with-simple-json-library)

In DB-Language: i have a database with some tables. Now, i can only read "select * from table" but i want to read the column (or attribute) from it.

---

The Structure (raw data json):

```
{
"PARENT1":
{
"child_attr1":"0.00","child_attr2":"0.30"
},
"PARENT2":
{
"child_attr1":"0.10","child_attr2":"0.12"
},
"PARENT3":
{
"child_attr1":"0.03","child_attr2":"0.45"
}
}
```

---

The Code:

```
public static HttpResponse http(String url, String body) {    
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(body);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);

        String json_content = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        //System.out.println(json_content);

        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object resultObject = parser.parse(json_content);

            if (resultObject instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray array=(JSONArray)resultObject;
                for (Object object : array) {
                    JSONObject obj =(JSONObject)object;
                    System.out.println(obj.get("Parent"));
                    System.out.println(obj.get("Child"));
                    //System.out.println("case1"); 
                }

            } else if (resultObject instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject obj =(JSONObject)resultObject;
                System.out.println(obj.get("PARENT2"));
                //System.out.println("case2"); 
                //THIS KNOT WORKS BUT IT GIVES ME ALL VALUES OF THE ATTRIBUTES 


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO: handle exception
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I understand your Engish. I don't understand your question because you mention some tables and some code but you don't include how you used that code, the definition of those tables nor the error you got on your attempts

Comment: I edited my question. I hope this is better and thanks for your help!

Comment: Whats the question again? And can you provide the JSON structure as well?

Comment: Your question is still rather vague. Could you supply us with the structure of the JSON data? And tell us which nodes you're trying to read. And what do you mean with reading the attribute from a table? Is this part of your JSON-question, or is it a separate question (in which case, you should create a separate question for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 1 "root" `JSONObject`, containing 3 nodes, each an instance of `JSONObject`. These 3 nodes each contains 2 nested nodes. json-simple will treat these as strings, if you traverse through the structure.

To print out the contents of your parents, you'd have to do something similar to:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

JSONObject parents = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("filename"));

JSONObject parent1 = (JSONObject) parents.get("PARENT1");
JSONObject parent2 = (JSONObject) parents.get("PARENT2");
JSONObject parent3 = (JSONObject) parents.get("PARENT3");

System.out.println("Parent 1");
System.out.println("\tChild 1: " + parent1.get("child_attr1"));
System.out.println("\tChild 2: " + parent1.get("child_attr2"));

System.out.println("Parent 2");
System.out.println("\tChild 1: " + parent2.get("child_attr1"));
System.out.println("\tChild 2: " + parent2.get("child_attr2"));

System.out.println("Parent 3");
System.out.println("\tChild 1: " + parent3.get("child_attr1"));
System.out.println("\tChild 2: " + parent3.get("child_attr2"));
```

This would ouput

```
Parent 1
    Child 1: 0.00
    Child 2: 0.30
Parent 2
    Child 1: 0.10
    Child 2: 0.12
Parent 3
    Child 1: 0.03
    Child 2: 0.45
```

If you want to be able to iterate over all the childs, you should define each parent as a `JSONArray`, and each child as a `JSONObject`

```
{
    "PARENT1": [
        {"child_attr1": "0.00"},
        {"child_attr2": "0.30"}
    ],
    "PARENT2": [
        {"child_attr1": "0.10"},
        {"child_attr2": "0.12"}
    ],
    "PARENT3": [
        {"child_attr1": "0.14"},
        {"child_attr2": "0.45"}
    ]
}
```

If your structure would always follow this sample: 1 root object with x-amount parent array objects, each with y-amount child objects, where the child objects never have any nested nodes, one way to iterate over all of them would be:

```
Iterator<?> i = parents.keySet().iterator();
// Alternative, if you don't need the name of the key of the parent node:
// Iterator<?> i = parents.values().iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    String parentKey = (String) i.next();
    JSONArray p = (JSONArray) parents.get(parentKey);
    System.out.println(parentKey);

    // If you don't need the name of the parent key node, 
    // replace the above with:
    // JSONArray p = (JSONArray) i.next();
    // Remember to use the alternative iterator-definition above as well

    for(Object o : p) {
        JSONObject child = (JSONObject) o;
        System.out.println("\t" + child.keySet() + ": " + child.values());
    }
}
```

The above (with the parent node names) would output:

```
PARENT1
    [child_attr1]: [0.00]
    [child_attr2]: [0.30]
PARENT3
    [child_attr1]: [0.14]
    [child_attr2]: [0.25]
PARENT2
    [child_attr1]: [0.10]
    [child_attr2]: [0.12]
```

When calling `#keySet()` and `#values()` on the child node, it will return as a Set and a Collection, respectively. When using `#toString()` on these, the output will be printed enclosed in brackets (`[keys/values]`). You can of course just ask for an array, and then the first entry, to get the lonely key/value: `child.keySet().toArray()[0]` and `child.values().toArray()[0]`. This won't of course work, if you have nested nodes *inside* your child nodes - in such case, it would only print the first key/value for the particular node.

Comment: Really, i thank you eli! That's a complete answer! :)