# I can't fetch dogs/cats/fish name , age, colour, friendly from my JSON file

Tags: java, json, libgdx

It show the full JSON file I want to partly like dogs, cats, fish separately

**MyGdxGame.java**

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private Stage stage;
    public static AssetManager manager;
    private com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image image;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        stage = new Stage();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        manager = new AssetManager();


        manager.load("badlogic.jpg", Texture.class);

        manager.load("song.mp3", Music.class);

        manager.finishLoading();

        image = new Image(manager.get("badlogic.jpg", Texture.class));
        image.setBounds(20, 30, 200, 200);
        Music music = manager.get("song.mp3", Music.class);

        music.play();

        image.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveBy(300, 200), Actions.rotateBy(300, 200)));

        stage.addActor(image);

        JsonReader temp = new JsonReader();
        JsonValue base = temp.parse(Gdx.files.internal("pets.json"));
        JsonValue pets = base.get("pets");
        for (JsonValue component : base.get("pets")) {
            Pets dog = new Pets();

            Pets cat = new Pets();
            Pets fish = new Pets();
            Json json = new Json();

            System.out.println("\n\n name : " + component.getString("name"));

            System.out.println("age : " + component.getString("age"));
            System.out.println("colour : " + component.getString("colour"));
            if (component.has("friendly")) {
                System.out.println("friendly : " + component.getString("friendly"));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        super.render();

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

**Pets.java**

*this is pets class where object is define*

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pets {

   public int age;
   public String name;
   public String colour;
   public boolean friendly;

   public Pets(String  name,int age, String colour, boolean friendly) {
      this.age = age;
      this.name = name;
      this.colour = colour;
      this.friendly = friendly;
   }

   public Pets() {
   }

   public int getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getColour() {
      return colour;
   }

   public void setColour(String colour) {
      this.colour = colour;
   }

   public boolean isFriendly() {
      return friendly;
   }

   public void setFriendly(boolean friendly) {
      this.friendly = friendly;
   }
}
```

> pets.json

**this is my json file where i want to fetch data**

```
{
    pets: [
        {
            age:12,
            name:"tommy",
            colour:"balck",
            friendly:"true"
        },
        {
            age:5,
            name:"bob",
            colour:"white",
            friendly:"true"
        },
        {
            age:22,
            name:"fishy",
            colour:"white"

        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**

```
I want to output   dogs name=tommy dogs age=12 dogs color=black dogs friendly=true
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want to fetch data from json file

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926353/how-to-read-json-file-into-java-with-simple-json-library

Comment: code improvements

Comment: http://json-b.net/
https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/

Comment: Which implementation of `JsonReader` are you using?