# How to add Json objects to an arrayList as integer values?

Tags: java, json

Im transfering data from a json file to an arrayList in order to filter those values. The problem is that i want to access to especific data of the json object. In this case i want to create an arrayList with the "value" numbers.

**JSON file:**

```
{
      "I": [
        {
          "value": 2984,
          "time": 1563550463
        },
        {
          "value": 2984,
          "time": 1563550465
        },
        {
          "value": 2984,
          "time": 1563550467
        },
        {
          "value": 2984,
          "time": 1563550469
        },
           ...
```

**Main class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject obj = JSONUtils.getJSONObjectFromFile("/15s_60bpm_ecg_data.json");
        String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(obj); 
        for(String string : names) {
            //System.out.println(string); 
            //System.out.println(string + ":" + obj.get(string)); 
        }

        JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("II");
        CargarArray(jsonArray);
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            //System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i)); 
        }
    }


    public static void CargarArray(JSONArray jsonArray){
        ArrayList<Integer> Lista = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Lista.add(json.getInt("value"));
                    for (int j = 0; j < Lista.size(); j++) {
                        Lista.get(j);
                        System.out.println(j);
                        }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

What i expect is to get an arrayList with all the "values"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read json file into java with simple JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926353/how-to-read-json-file-into-java-with-simple-json-library)

Comment: what problem do you face here? any stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue and you will see that the list showing all data of values parameter in integer formate.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject obj = JSONUtils.getJSONObjectFromFile("/15s_60bpm_ecg_data.json");
    String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(obj); 
    for(String string : names) {
        //System.out.println(string); 
        //System.out.println(string + ":" + obj.get(string)); 
    }

    JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("I");
    CargarArray(jsonArray);
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i)); 
    }
}


public static void CargarArray(JSONArray jsonArray){
    ArrayList<Integer> Lista = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            try {
                JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Lista.add(json.getInt("value"));

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
       for (int j = 0; j < Lista.size(); j++) {

            System.out.println(Lista.get(j));
      }
}

}
```

Comment: Thank sooooooooo much :)

Comment: Np let me know if there is any issue i will solve it