# Parsing internal JSON file in JSONArray in Java using org.json

Tags: java, json, file, parsing

I would like to be able to parse a JSON file that is structured something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
      "first": "name",
      "secound": "name",
      "last": "name"
    },
    "skills": [
      "python",
      "javascript"
    ],
    "otherInfo": {
      "something": 45,
      "something2": 49
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": {
      "first": "name",
      "secound": "name",
      "last": "name"
    },
    "skills": [
      "python",
      "javascript"
    ],
    "otherInfo": {
      "something": 45,
      "something2": 49
    }
  }
etc...
]
```

into something *looking like*

```
array(
    [0] => array(
                   0 => "id"
                   1 => "firstname"
                   2 => "otherData"
                ),
    [1] => array(
                   0 => "id"
                   1 => "firstname"
                   2 => "otherData"
                ),
etc...
)
```

I'm pretty sure i have an idea on how to convert it into the format I want, but im having trouble actually reading the data from the file.

The two major issues im having:

- Reading it from inside the jar.
- Most of the examples used json.simple, and the json library i'm using doesn't seem to have that.

I tried some examples online, and a couple of the answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926353/how-to-read-json-file-into-java-with-simple-json-library)
but no luck the biggest issue is that all of them are giving examples for reading an external file, while I'm trying to read one that is packaged inside the jar.

My project tree:

```
MyProject
      L src
          L myPackage
                  L MyClass.java
                  L MyJsonFile.json
```

The closest thing that I'm guessing almost worked is this (from the link above):

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

//code

JSONArray myJSONArray = new JSONArray(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("myFile.json"));
```

But that only seems to throw an error:
`org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to me you should delete the stuff abut the JSON format/mapping and make your question about reading from the jar file - you'll get more help if the question is as targeted as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is [org.json.JSONArray](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html) will only accept `String`,`Collection` or `Array` but you are trying to pass the `InputStream` object. which is what error messages also says

> org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array

So first convert the `InputStream` into `String`

```
InputStream  inputStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("myFile.json");

InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  String str;
  while((str = reader.readLine())!= null){
     sb.append(str);
  }
```

And then convert it into `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray myJSONArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
```

After here you can iterate the `JSONArray` using for loop, like [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json)